# Python: DES-ECB encryption with two different keys result in the same ciphertext

Tags: python, encryption, des

I'am trying to encrypt the plaintext `6d65737361676531` (which is in hexadecimal) with the keys `0000000000000000` and `0000000000000001` (both in hexadecimal) using the DES cipher in ECB mode from Crypto.Cipher. But for some reason both `ciphertext1_hex` and `ciphertext2_hex` are equal `3bd2ac43547a7961`, i.e. they result in the same ciphertext. Does anyone have any idea about why this is the case?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

key1_hex = "0000000000000000"
key2_hex = "0000000000000001"

key1 = key1_hex.decode("hex")
key2 = key2_hex.decode("hex")

des1 = DES.new(key1, DES.MODE_ECB)
des2 = DES.new(key2, DES.MODE_ECB)

plaintext_hex = "6d65737361676531"
plaintext = plaintext_hex.decode("hex")

ciphertext1 = des1.encrypt(plaintext)
ciphertext2 = des2.encrypt(plaintext)

ciphertext1_hex = ciphertext1.encode("hex")
ciphertext2_hex = ciphertext2.encode("hex")
```

Comment: Of course one should not use DES nor in ECB mode if security is the goal.

Comment: Note that hex `0000000000000000` and `0000000000000001` are [weak DES keys](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32456/4747) as are many others and should not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a DES key it's only the first 7 bits of each byte that are actual key material (giving a DES key of 56 bit)  .. the last bit of each byte is a parity bit. So the two keys are actually the same key. Some implementations would complain if the parity bit ain't correct. But this one apparently don't.